# CGAL detect_features() creates unprotectable features

Tags: mesh, cgal

Based on [this](https://doc.cgal.org/latest/Mesh_3/Mesh_3_2mesh_polyhedral_domain_with_surface_inside_8cpp-example.html) example (Remeshing a Polyhedral Domain with Surfaces in the [3D Mesh Generation Manual](https://doc.cgal.org/latest/Mesh_3/index.html#title17)), I want to mesh a cube-shaped domain with its midplane protected (see the code below). However, `make_mesh_3` throws an assertion violation:

```
CGAL ERROR: assertion violation!
Expr: minimal_size_ > 0 || sq_d > 0
```

Nevermind the triviality of the example, it's just to show the problem. Based on [this](http://cgal-discuss.949826.n4.nabble.com/Make-mesh-with-features-feature-lines-duplicated-overlapping-or-very-close-td4661083.html) discussion, I think the issue is that `detect_features` creates polylines that intersect each other (perimeter of the midplane intersects the cube edges, and both are added as features).

Are intersecting polyhedra not allowed in the meshdomain? If so, is there a way to access and manipulate the results of `detect_features` to process conflicting features? I'm trying to figure out how polylines are stored in the mesh domain, but I'm getting nowhere.

### Cube with Midplane

```
// --- External Includes ---
#include <CGAL/Exact_predicates_inexact_constructions_kernel.h>
#include <CGAL/Mesh_polyhedron_3.h>

#include <CGAL/Polyhedral_mesh_domain_with_features_3.h>
#include <CGAL/Mesh_triangulation_3.h>
#include <CGAL/Mesh_complex_3_in_triangulation_3.h>
#include <CGAL/Mesh_criteria_3.h>
#include <CGAL/make_mesh_3.h>

// CGAL types
namespace cgal {

using Kernel            = CGAL::Exact_predicates_inexact_constructions_kernel;
using ConcurrencyTag    = CGAL::Sequential_tag;
using PolyhedronSurface = CGAL::Mesh_polyhedron_3<Kernel>::type;

using MeshDomain        = CGAL::Polyhedral_mesh_domain_with_features_3<Kernel>;
using Tr                = CGAL::Mesh_triangulation_3<MeshDomain,CGAL::Default,ConcurrencyTag>::type;
using Triangulation     = CGAL::Mesh_complex_3_in_triangulation_3<Tr>;
using MeshCriteria      = CGAL::Mesh_criteria_3<Tr>;

using Point             = cgal::MeshDomain::Point_3;
}



int main()
{
    // Define points for the cube and midPlane
    std::vector<cgal::Point> points = 
    {
        cgal::Point(  1.0,    0.0,    0.0),
        cgal::Point(  1.0,    1.0,    0.0),
        cgal::Point(  0.0,    1.0,    0.0),
        cgal::Point(  0.0,    0.0,    0.0),
        cgal::Point(  1.0,    0.0,    1.0),
        cgal::Point(  1.0,    1.0,    1.0),
        cgal::Point(  0.0,    1.0,    1.0),
        cgal::Point(  0.0,    0.0,    1.0),

        cgal::Point(  1.0,    0.0,    0.5),
        cgal::Point(  1.0,    1.0,    0.5),
        cgal::Point(  0.0,    1.0,    0.5),
        cgal::Point(  0.0,    0.0,    0.5)
    };

    // Create polyhedra
    cgal::PolyhedronSurface cube, midPlane;
    cube.make_triangle( points[0],  points[3],  points[1]);
    cube.make_triangle( points[1],  points[3],  points[2]);
    cube.make_triangle( points[4],  points[5],  points[7]);
    cube.make_triangle( points[5],  points[6],  points[7]);

    cube.make_triangle( points[0],  points[4],  points[3]);
    cube.make_triangle( points[3],  points[4],  points[7]);
    cube.make_triangle( points[1],  points[2],  points[5]);
    cube.make_triangle( points[2],  points[6],  points[5]);

    cube.make_triangle( points[2],  points[3],  points[6]);
    cube.make_triangle( points[3],  points[7],  points[6]);
    cube.make_triangle( points[0],  points[1],  points[5]);
    cube.make_triangle( points[0],  points[5],  points[4]);

    midPlane.make_triangle( points[8],  points[9],  points[10]);
    midPlane.make_triangle( points[8],  points[10], points[11]);

    // Triangulation
    cgal::MeshDomain meshDomain( midPlane, cube );
    meshDomain.detect_features();

    cgal::MeshCriteria meshCriteria(    CGAL::parameters::facet_angle   = 30,
                                        CGAL::parameters::edge_size     = 0.2 );

    auto triangulation = CGAL::make_mesh_3<cgal::Triangulation>(    meshDomain,
                                                                    meshCriteria );

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

From [here](https://doc.cgal.org/latest/Mesh_3/classCGAL_1_1Polyhedral__mesh__domain__with__features__3.html):

> This surface must be free of intersection.

In your case, the bounding box and midplane intersect. If you want to mesh this geometry, those meshes need to be connected together ahead of meshing.

If you look at the [example in section 3.3.2 here](https://doc.cgal.org/latest/Mesh_3/index.html#Mesh_33DPolyhedralDomains), you see a similar example with an internal geometry that is enclosed away from the bounding box.

detect_features() doesn't intersect non-intersecting inputs: it just  looks for features in an existing mesh (and adds them to the domain so meshing will respect them).

Comment: Thanks for the explanation, though the wording on the requirements is a bit misleading. It kind of hints at self-intersections rather than intersections between the specified surfaces.

Do you have any suggestions on how to connect the ```Polyhedron_3```s? The boolean operations in the Polygon_mesh_processing package only work on surfaces that bound a domain (so the midplane is out of the question).

Comment: I tried to begin with [corefinement](https://doc.cgal.org/latest/Polygon_mesh_processing/group__PMP__corefinement__grp.html#ga6447dee822aaf92016f34512ce0b3456) but that won't work (throws ```s == LEFT_TURN``` assertion violation). 

Do I have to find the intersections, split existing edges, and insert new ones on my own?

Comment: I don't know of a really direct way to do this in CGAL. I think corefinement requires two surface meshes that bound volumes. Depending on your actual situation, you may be able to come up with a workflow using the [slicer](https://doc.cgal.org/latest/Polygon_mesh_processing/index.html#title52). But there doesn't seem to be a direct way to connect your meshes together.

Comment: The surfaces for corefinement are not required to  bound volumes. However the midplane must split the cube in two volumes.

Answer (score 1):

For your cube it should be easy to construct a polyhedral complex, that is three surfaces, namely the upper and lower part of the cube, and the mid-square. Have a look at [this example](https://doc.cgal.org/latest/Mesh_3/index.html#title35).

Comment: True that works for the example, but how should I approach cases where I can't break up the geometry into volume-bounding surfaces (eg.: protect only one triangle of the midplane)?

Sorry for the extra requirements, I should have been more descriptive with my question.